# How can I force hg merge to be interactive?

Tags: mercurial, msbuild, merge, cruisecontrol.net, interactive

I am running an automated hg merge under CruiseControl.NET as part of an MSBuild job.  For some reason the merge runs in non-interactive mode even though I have not specified `-y` in the command.  This is causing unexpected results since it takes the first option when prompted about a conflict, I'd rather it just times out and fails so we know we need to look at it manually.

So two questons:

1) Why is it running non-iteractively when I haven't given it a `-y`?
2) Is there a way to force the hg merge to be interactive so the job will timeout and fail?

Comment: I'm betting it's detecting that it has no console attached and does the sane thing - ignores interactive mode.

Comment: I think so too but I don't know how or why it's detecting it's running headless or what I can do to override that.

Comment: I was able to confirm that running hg inside MSBuild makes it run in non-interactive mode. I was also able to get it to run in interactive by forcing it to run in a separate command window within MSBuild like this: "start cmd /k &quot; <hg command> &quote; ". However, this would hang and fail, then leave the repo in a messy, unresolved state which would throw other builds off the rails. Though I got what I wanted it was not what I needed. I'm going to try to sort this out by doing this in PoweShell rather than MSBuild. Thanks for all your help everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12187000/125356), it looks like Mercurial auto-detects if it is running under a TTY or is headless, thus doesn't prompt you.  You could override this by supplying the `ui.interactive` config option:

```
hg --config ui.interactive=yes
```

Answer (score 3):

I think better idea is to use `hg merge --tool internal:merge`. Mercurial will try to make automatic merge but will fail if there are any conflicts. There are [other options](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#id4) possible here.

I am using it daily after automatic pull from external ClearCase repository and it works great. If there are any conflicts than my  CI job just fails imediatelly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that but I don't know if it will override the non-interactive behavior I'm trying to stop.

Comment: It didn't, still runs non-interactive :(  I tried a few other options from you link, also with no luck.  Part of the problem may be that I'm running into manifest merges, not just file merges.  For examply, where a file is modified in source but deleted in destination.  These are treated differently and I think trip a prompt before even the basic internal merge attempt happens.

Comment: Mercurial v 2.1.1 installed as part of TortoiseHg 2.3.1 (x64), CCnet v 1.6.7981.1, MSBuild Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1.