# Mercurial (HG) pull parameters: username and password

Tags: php, mercurial

I have to write a script that automates pulling from a mercurial repo.  Is there anyway I can perform an `hg pull -u` that includes passing the requested username and password in the same command? I know there's an interactive method which is the default behaviour, and I don't want to save the username and password in hgrc or elsewhere because it will be used by multiple users, so is there a way to pass the username and password via the command line?
I tried using `proc_open` in PHP but that wasn't working as well as echoing out to STDIN.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found two solutions:

1. Explicitly provide the URL, including full credentials:

> `hg pull -u https://user:pass@host/path`

2. Provide the credentials with --config, using * as a prefix (from Victor's answer):

> `hg pull -u
>   --config auth.x.prefix=*
>   --config auth.x.username=user
>   --config auth.x.password=pass`

Comment: Bonus info for solution 2: `prefix=*` doesn't work for me when the `[auth]` section in my actual config file already contains such an entry for the same hoster. Example: my config file contains `bb.prefix = https://bitbucket.org/` and `bb.username = christianspecht`. Pulling from Bitbucket with solution 2 only works for me with `--config auth.x.prefix=https://bitbucket.org/` instead of `--config auth.x.prefix=*`.

Answer (score 7):

Solution 2 is specific to a repository. Do

```
[auth]
x.prefix = *
x.username = USERNAME
x.password = PASSWORD
```

to make it apply to all repositories. Also, if you put this in "~/.hgrc" and give that permission of 600 you don't have to do the HGRCPATH trick. Just leave it there.

Answer (score 5):

Passing the password on the command line is **insecure** since other users can see it using `ps` and similar. What you should do is either:

1. Communicate with `hg` on the pipes you get back from `proc_open`. You'll need to carefully parse the output from Mercurial and feed it the username and password on stdin. Run Mercurial as:

   ```
   hg --config ui.interactive=yes
   ```

   to make sure that it will talk to you — otherwise I'm afraid that it detects that there is no TTY and wont prompt you at all.
2. Write a temporary configuration file with an [`[auth]` section](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth). It will look like this:

   ```
   [auth]
   x.prefix = output of "hg paths default"
   x.username = USERNAME
   x.password = PASSWORD
   ```

   (The `x` is not important, it can be anything.)
   Make sure that the file is only readable by the user you're running the script as. Then set the `HGRCPATH` environment variable to point to the file and execute Mercurial. Delete the file when you're done!

There is a [libhg PHP library](https://bitbucket.org/xrstf/libhg) for the [command server](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CommandServer), but I don't see anything about usernames or passwords for pull or clone in that library. The library is work in progress, but when it's more mature I suggest using it. But for now the above approaches should help you along.

Answer (score 2):

Thats worked:

```
hg --config auth.rc.prefix=http://host/ --config auth.rc.username=user --config auth.rc.password=password pull -u http://host/full/path/to/repo
```

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to use the `--config` switch to do that like this:

```
hg --config auth.username=USERNAME --config auth.password=PASSWORD pull -u
```

I personally have never done this, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: No doesn't work, ignoring invalid [auth] key 'username'
ignoring invalid [auth] key 'password'