# Jenkins, Kiln and Mercurial: abort: http authorization required for [repository]

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, kiln

I've upgraded the OS and the Jenkins that was running on it from Windows XP and an ancient version of Jenkins (installed in 2012). So now I'm on Windows 7 and Jenkins 2.19.1 (the latest at time of writing). Other than that, the only different is that I do not have a jenkins user, and it's running as a service instead of locally on the desktop.

I need to update a repository that is outside my Jenkins workspace. Let's call is C:\Repos\Operations. Doing an hg pull -u in a windows batch command and I get this:

```
   C:\Repos\Operations>hg pull --debug -u 
   using https://xxx.kilnhg.com/Code/Repositories/Operations
   sending capabilities command
   xxx.kilnhg.com certificate successfully verified
   abort: http authorization required for https://xxx.kilnhg.com/Code/Repositories/Operations
```

It works fine if I do it in the cmd.exe. I've been searching for hours for an answer. Using `hg showconfig --debug` the only difference between doing it in the cmd and having `hg showconfig --debug` in the jenkins windows batch command is the following 2 lines:

```
read config from: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\mercurial.ini
read config from: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.hgrc
```

But those files do not exist on my system. So, in theory, it should be reading everything from the same settings location, but it's not.

Does someone have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, so this goes under 'Answer': per your comment it does not find the correct '.hgrc' file. Have you tried providing the username/password in the batch command, like here [Mercurial (HG) pull parameters: username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185048/mercurial-hg-pull-parameters-username-and-password) ?